# Move Complete Path in Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, path, move

Using Windows 10 and File Explorer.

Is there a way to do this that's optimal?

I want to move files from one folder to another, but I also want to recreate the folder architecture from the source that contains those files in the target.

These easiest way I've come up with to do this is to copy the entire folder architecture to the target, and then selectively delete things from both the target and the source until it looks like only the parts of the architecture that I want have been moved.

For example, suppose my architecture looks like this:

Folder A contains 2 subfolders

Subfolder AA contains 1 subfolder

SubSubfolder AAA contains two files

File AAA1 (this is the file I want to move)

File AAA2

Subfolder AB

I want to move File AAA1 to empty Folder B

Folder B

But I want it to look like this when I'm done

Folder B

Subfolder AA contains 1 subfolder

SubSubfolder AAA contains one files

File AAA1

In the end, Folder B will contain some, but not all of the architecture of Folder A, as needed.

The goal here is that I am deprecating File AAA1 to Folder B, and keeping File AAA2 in Folder A. But I can find both if I need them.

Trying to clarify for Senor CMasMas:

I have a folder tree with deprecated files in it and new ones. I want to be able to run a script, feed it the name of a deprecated file and path, and have it move it to the same spot in a second folder tree (and perhaps create folders and subfolders along the way). When done, I will be able to go to the same location in both folder trees, and find the new file in one, and the deprecated file in the other.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish via the file explorer confuses me beyond reason.  If you could somehow clarify (and not elaborate), please do so.

Comment: No way to be that selective in File Explorer alone. You would need a funtion -- but how would it know what you consider the "top-level" folder? That would be needed to know how many levels of ancesotor folders to create in the target folder....

Comment: I think the top level (Folder B above) could be defined as a default.